# How to download sequence alignments against UniProtKB sequence database for a particular Pfam Id using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to download sequence alignments for families against the UniProtKB sequence database as shown in the example below using R code. Can someone kindly suggest me how to?

```
https://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF02171/alignment/uniprot/format?format=pfam&alnType=uniprot&order=t&case=l&gaps=default&download=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code served my purpose.

```
library(readr)
pfam_url <-
  'https://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF02171/alignment/uniprot/format?format=pfam&alnType=uniprot&order=t&case=l&gaps=default&download=1'
seqs <-
  read_table(
    pfam_url,
    col_names = FALSE,
    col_types = cols(X1 = col_character(), X2 = col_character())
  )
```